# Laravel query nested relations

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following model schema

**Products** (can have many stores on table product_stores; can have many chains on table product_chains)

**Stores** (have one chain on column chain_id; can have many products on table product_stores; have a spatial location column)

**Chains** (can have many stores; can have many products on table product_chains)

I need to retrieve the products that match a certain expression (I am using MATCH (name) AGAINST), and I need to order them by the distance to the user's location. The distance to the user's location should be the minimum distance to any of the product stores, that are associated to the product through on either of the tables (product_stores, product_chains).

I achieved this for the stores that are associated to the product through the stores table, but I'm still not able to do it for the stores associated through Chains (nested).

For the direct stores I'm doing it like this:

```
    $productList = $productList->withCount(['stores as distance' => function($query) use ($centerPoint) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("coalesce(MIN( GLength( LineStringFromWKB( LineString( location, GeomFromText('" . $centerPoint . "') ) ) ) ) )"));
    }])->having('distance', '<', $distance)->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
```

For the chains' stores I haven't reached a solution. Any ideas? I'm also wondering about ways to improve the performance on this query. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: I think you need to does some [one to many relation in single query](https://romik-mk.medium.com/laravel-one-to-many-relation-in-single-query-5587697c259) , that will help you - read this for your answer,  
else you have to does nested query